# Quickly re-projecting spatial data in python

Tags: python, transform, geopandas, pyproj

I have a geodataframe with a local projection (EPSG:2263) that I want to transform to WGS84(global) in order to add basemap interactivity within python. However, when transforming this data, the runtime for this block of code is *hours* long and extremely impractical, I only have ~40,000 polygons that need to be transformed.
code I am using:

```
gdf.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
```

Does anyone know of quicker ways to re-project somewhat large datasets in python?

I have done this call before with a smaller dataset to test it out, and indeed it took nearly a minute with only 150 records.

Comment: I suppose the polygons itself are also very large? One potential to speed this up is to install pygeos with the development version of geopandas, see https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency